# click event not binding for first time but bound after refresh the page

Tags: jquery

I faced a strange problem that the click event of a  tag not working for first time open the page but working fine after refreshing the same page. I checked by jquery audit, there is no event bound for the  tag first time, but a click event is bound after refreshing it.

the code slip is as following:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script src="http://dev.wenba.ca/static/js/jquery.2.js?v=20150409" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://dev.wenba.ca/static/js/jquery.form.js?v=20150409" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://dev.wenba.ca/static/mobile/js/app.js?v=20150409" type="text/javascript"></script>
   ...
</head>
...
<div class="aw-question-detail">
...
    <a class="aw-invite-replay" href="#"><i class="icon icon-inviteask"></i> <?php _e('invite reply'); ?></a>
...
</div>
...
```

in mobile/js/app.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
...
    $('.aw-invite-replay').click(function()
    {
        alert("click invite reply");
        if ($(this).parents('.aw-question-detail').find('.aw-invite-box').is(':visible'))
        {
            $(this).parents('.aw-question-detail').find('.aw-invite-box').hide();
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }else
        {
            $(this).parents('.aw-question-detail').find('.aw-invite-box').show();
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
...

});
```

Comment: try `$('.aw-invite-replay').on('click', function() { // rest of code here; });`

Comment: Try logging `console.log($('.aw-invite-replay').length);` just before the event binding.

Comment: @ indubitablee, thanks your help but it does not work.

Comment: @ Diego, I add console.log($('.aw-invite-replay').length); before the event binding, first time open the page, the result is 0, after refresh it, the result is 1. it seems that the element is not created for first time, but I don't know why

Comment: does moving the `mobile/js/app` script to the bottom of the body do anything?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments on the question I believe your problem is on the HTML and not in your script. Make sure that the first time the page loads, the `.aw-invite-replay` element is in the DOM. You can check this with any browser's developer tools.

If the element is there you could also try to move every `script` tag to the bottom of the `body` as suggested in question's comments.

Comment: Hi Diego, I don't think so. The html code is fine. I can find it in the DOM. I think it might caused the by the referrer page. the referrer page is also include the mobile/js/app.js. When I open the current page from referrer page. The debug code of console.log($('.aw-invite-replay').length); in $(document).ready(function () not tricked, but is tricked in the referrer page, so the result is 0. But refresh the current page, the debug code runs again and the result is 1.

Comment: I didn't understand what you tried to explain. Check my updated answer for one more option and if it doesn't work, try to explain all the referrer scenario in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine when moving js tag to the bottom of the body. Thanks you all.